# How to add items to wishlist or shopping list using amazon ask-sdk-core

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to add products in amazon shopping list or wishlist, I am using ask-sdk-core module and find a method 'serviceClientFactory.getListManagementServiceClient()' to do that.

```
const listClient = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getListManagementServiceClient();
const addRequest = {
        value: 'mobiles',
        status: listStatuses.ACTIVE
      };
listClient.createListItem(shoppinglistId, addRequest);
```

Items are added in alexa app shopping list.But not visible in amazon website or amazon app.

I am also tried to add items manually in alexa app shopping list, but not visible in amazon website.

I am using same account in both amazon website and alexa app.

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any way to do this currently.
The List API just allows to add it to the Alexa Lists.